# ASP.NET Could not find control in ControlParamater

Tags: asp.net, controlparameter

I'm pretty lost at this point (been working at it for a while not and am hitting a wall / deadline) but the error message I am being thrown is after I hit btnupdate to update the fields in the database.

Full Error Message:

```
Could not find control 'txtTitle' in ControlParameter 'Title'.
```

Page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

<div class="floater">
<h3>Books</h3>
<asp:DropDownList
    id="DropDownList_Books"
    DataSourceId="srcBooks"
    DataTextField="Title"
    DataValueField="Id"
    Runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="View Detials" Width="106px" 
        onclick="btnSelect_Click" />
</div>

<asp:GridView
    id="grdBooks"
    DataSourceID="srcBooks_Description"
    Runat="server" Visible="False" />

    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" onclick="btnEdit_Click" Text="Edit" />

</div>

<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" onclick="btnCancel_Click"
    Text="Cancel" Visible="False" />

<asp:FormView
    id="frmEditBook"
    DataKeyNames="Cat_Id"
    DataSourceId="srcBooks_Description"
    DefaultMode="Edit"
    Runat="server" Visible="False" 

    style="z-index: 1; left: 391px; top: 87px; position: absolute; height: 111px; width: 206px" >
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label
        id="lblTitle"
        Text="Title:"
        AssociatedControlID="txtTitle"
        Runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox
        id="txtTitle"
        Text='<%#Bind("Title")%>'
        Runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label
        id="lblDescription"
        Text="Description:"
        AssociatedControlID="txtDescription"
        Runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox
        id="txtDescription"
        Text='<%#Bind("Description")%>'
        Runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button
        id="btnUpdate"
        Text="Update"
        CommandName="Update"
        Runat="server" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="srcBooks" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Data Source=****;;Initial Catalog=***;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****" 
    onselecting="srcBooks_Selecting" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT Title,Id FROM PARTIN_ID">

</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="srcBooks_Description" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Data Source=****, 14330&quot;;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****" 
    onselecting="srcBooks_Selecting" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM PARTIN_INFO WHERE Cat_ID=@Id" UpdateCommand="UPDATE PARTIN_INFO SET Title=@Title,
        Description=@Description WHERE Cat_Id=@Id">
<SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter
            Name="Id"
            Type="int32"                
            ControlID="DropDownList_Books"
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter Name="Title" ControlId="txtTitle" PropertyName="Text"/>
          <asp:ControlParameter Name="Description" ControlId="txtDescription" PropertyName="Text"/>
          <asp:ControlParameter Name="Id" ControlId="DropDownList_Books" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
      </UpdateParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void srcBooks_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grdBooks.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmEditBook.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmEditBook.Visible = true;
        btnCancel.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            srcBooks_Description.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            // Handle the Exception.
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never post connection string information to your database. That's only asking for trouble other than what you are currently experiencing.....

Comment: Thanks for editing those my bad!

Answer (score 4):

You -can- refer to the control adequately.

You need to prefix the controlid value of your update parameters with the control id of your enclosing view (FormView 'frmEditBook' in this case)

Replace the UpdateParamters section of your SqlDataSource with the following:

```
<UpdateParameters>
   <asp:ControlParameter Name="Title" ControlId="frmEditBook$txtTitle" PropertyName="Text"/>
   <asp:ControlParameter Name="Description" ControlId="frmEditBook$txtDescription" PropertyName="Text"/>
   <asp:ControlParameter Name="Id" ControlId="DropDownList_Books" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
</UpdateParameters>
```

Note that

```
ControlId="DropDownList_Books"
```

remains the same as this control is not within the bounds of the FormView.

I don't recommend using the 'full name' provided by the browser... particularly if you're using master pages... it could change as you rearrange your layouts.

Comment: I had the same problem and this work for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the problem is the context.  You can also put your sqldatasource inside the formview where the control being refered to is (not properly and very limited but could work)

Let's say you have a detailsview with two dropdowns in it, and one is dependant from another.  What works for me is to put the Datasource in the same context (parent control) as the control refered and this will eliminate the need to reference the full path of the control.

My two cents is that this is very reminiscent on how you must reference controls in Access Forms with subforms. :)

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server">
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <EditTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList id="ParentDDL" Datasource="SQLDataSource1">

          </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <EditTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList id="ParentDDL" Datasource="SQLDatasource2">

          </asp:DropDownList>
          <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * from table where field1=@field">
                                <SelectParameters>
                                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ParentDDL" Name="field" 
                                        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                                </SelectParameters>          
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </EditTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to your control with its full name.

You can easily find the control's full name when you open the page in the browser.  Simply view source and you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `txtTitle` is inside a FormView so it's not accesible in the way you're trying to do on the SqlDataSource. You can't access it direclty by ID.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you have an MSDN article that may help to to work with a FormView and SqlDataSource

Comment: 1. Would taking it out of a formview solve the problem or while that cause other errors 

2. Would what Jesse suggested work as a quick fix?

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look to the MSDN article. That's the proper way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't have used `<asp:ControlParameter..` but `<asp:Parameter..` and the SqlDataSource control with the help of the bind method is intelligent enough to locate the controls to get values from for the parameters.

Update this portion of the sqlDataSource this way:

```
  ....
 <UpdateParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String"/>
      <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String"/>
      <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32"/>
  </UpdateParameters>
 .....
```

Please note the Type attribute and supply the relevant type.

(The problem is SqlDataSource control cannot explicitly access controls defined in a databound control)